# Why does apache spark fails with org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder Exception in multi threaded environment?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the `sparkSession` object in multi-threaded environment. When I run the below code snippet in stand alone cluster mode, my application is getting crashed with `org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder` exception. Just to add, below code is only for  illustrating the use of `sparkSession` object in multi-threaded environment, my business use-case is more complex. My goal is to understand the usage of `sparkSession` in multi-threaded environment.

**Code Snippet:**

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()

val employeeIdList = getEmployeeIdList

val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40)

for(employeeId <- employeeIdList) {
  val runnable : Runnable = new Runnable {
  
  override def run(): Unit = {
    try {
      val cols = employeeHeader.split(",")
      val df = sparkSession
              .read
              .option("escape", "\"")
              .option("quote", "\"")
              .schema(EmployeeSchema.getInputSchema)
              .csv(outputPath + "/" + employeeId)
              .select(cols.map(col): _*)
              .show(500)
          } catch {
            case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
          }
        }
      }
      executorService.submit(runnable)
    }
    executorService.shutdown()
```

**Exception trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1068)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:143)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:654)
    at com.practice.reporting.MultiThreadedService$$anonfun$execute$1$$anon$1.run(MultiThreadedService.scala:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LiveListenerBus is stopped.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addToQueue(LiveListenerBus.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addToStatusQueue(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:120)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1065)
```

We are using `apache-spark-2.3.x`.